# sudoers file corrupted

Tags: 14.10, sudo

My server crashed and I had to restart it from the power button. However once I restarted it i can no longer run sudo. When I try I get

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I then ran

```
pkexec visudo
```

which returns

```
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿ï¿½uï¿½fZcï¿½fï¿½<ï¿½ï¿½^Fï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½^Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&^R& k^Nï¿½^[N)ï¿½ï¿½@{^Hï¿½Æ¼^Pï¿½ï¿½8^^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0,(iÈ¼4_ï¿ï¿½ï¿½d$9ï¿½ï¿½y^YWï¿½Å¼^O}ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½È¼0vï¿½ï¿½lE"G^A^@^Y1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½$
```

So how do I recreate my sudoers file, or am I boned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the default `/etc/sudoers` file in Trusty:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

You can replace your corrupted `/etc/sudoers` file with this one using a Live DVD:

1. Boot from a Live DVD
2. Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run `lsblk` to see to which block device your `root` partition on the drive is mapped to
4. Mount the `root` partition on the drive: `sudo mount /dev/<partition_block_device> /mnt` (where `<partition_block_device>` = `root` partition's block device)
5. Run `sudo gedit /mnt/etc/sudoers`
6. Paste in the content of the clean `/etc/sudoers` file
7. Save
8. Quit
9. Run `exit`
10. Reboot

Comment: Can I just use pkexec visudo to paste in the default text?

Comment: @Dowlers If you are able to do, sure

Comment: That worked thank you very much. Unfortunately other files are displaying the same corruption so I'll have to do a complete reinstall anyway.

Comment: Does it remove the iptables contents, ip address configurations etc ?